# Shiny R Date Input Pop Up message

Tags: r, shiny

I have a server file for an app which gets the stock information from yahoo finance, from a stock symbol which the user inputs. The server code which is relevant here is

```
dataInput <- reactive({
  getSymbols(input$symb, src = "yahoo", 
    from = input$dates[1],
    to = input$dates[2],
    auto.assign = FALSE)
})
```

and the ui.r code is

```
  textInput("symb", "Symbol", "^FTSE"),

  dateRangeInput("dates", 
    "Date range",
    start = "2015-01-01", 
    end = as.character(Sys.Date())),

  submitButton("Analysis"),width=6)
```

This gives the following

[image]

However if the user inputs a symbol that isn't correct or is not a stock, I get the following error

```
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=sdf&a=11&b=16&c=2014&d=1&e=25&f=2015&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=sdf&x=.csv'
```

This is good as it cannot open the url seeing as there does not exist a stock for the symbol they inputted. However I want a pop up message to occur saying that there does not exists a stock symbol for the one they have inserted. I have tried out ways to do this, including the bsAlert() approach but I just can't seem to do it. Any help would be great

Comment: can you share the code you tried to use? you could use a `tryCatch` ?

Comment: I attempted to go through using this tutorial ( http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyBS/shinyBS.pdf ) and going through the bsAlert function example. However my code doesn't make sense and i am completely stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `try/catch` when you get the symbols and make a `bsAlert` appear if there is an error:

**app.R**

```
library(quantmod)
library(shinyBS)

server<-function(input, output,session) {
  #get the symbol data
  symbolData<-reactive({
    #try/catch in case there is an error
    data<-tryCatch({
      #if there is a bsAlert, close it
      closeAlert(session, "alert")
      #try to get the symbols
      getSymbols(input$symb, src = "yahoo", 
               from = input$dates[1],
               to = input$dates[2],
               auto.assign = FALSE)},
               #if there is an error
               error=function(cond) {
                 #create the bsAlert
                 createAlert(session, inputId = "alert_anchor",
                             alertId="alert",
                             message = "Please enter a valid symbol",
                             type = "warning",
                             append="false",
                             dismiss = FALSE
                 )
                 #return an empty string
                 return("")
               })
    data
    })

  #as an example, output the table
  output$table<-renderDataTable({symbolData()})
}

ui<-fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      textInput("symb", "Symbol", "^FTSE"),
      bsAlert(inputId = "alert_anchor"),
      dateRangeInput("dates", 
                     "Date range",
                     start = "2015-01-01", 
                     end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
      submitButton("Submit")
    )),
  column(6, dataTableOutput("table"))

  ))
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked well but when i do it i get the following problem http://i.stack.imgur.com/RyeoR.png . The user can't continue or use the app unless they press stop in the console, and once they do, the following error comes up  http://i.stack.imgur.com/pYh7t.png . How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: would you mind posting the whole code, it's maybe related to the calculations you do with the data afterwards, maybe posting an empty string if an error is caught is not appropriate with the rest of your app

Comment: http://pastebin.com/w3zbLU1w I have the ui and server in there, I believe it is because it is collecting data from the website and so the statistical tests can't operate properly. Thanks for the help

Comment: try adding `validate(need(dataInput()!="",""))` in the reactive part of your `lg.ret` block`,  `lg.ret.vec` and after `output$plot <- renderPlot({`, it will check that you have `dataInput` and not run the code if it doesn't.

Comment: I was wondering if would change the date format to some other format such as `mm/dd/yyy' in date range input? because I have a dataset with this type of dates in it.